# What Is the Quickest Method to Solve $ A x = b $ for $ A $ Being Sparse Semi Definite Positive Matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab, numerical-linear-algebra, sparse-matrices

`A` is a huge scale of sparse symmetric semi-positive matrix. In MATLAB, the solution can be solved by

```
    b=A\b;
```

But it is very slow. Are there any quicker methods to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: What is the shape of $A$ and how many nonzero entries does it have?  How accurate do you need your solution to be?  You mentioned that $A$ is positive semidefinite.  If $A$ is positive definite, then the conjugate gradient method is a popular and good choice for solving $Ax = b$ to modest or medium accuracy.  If $A$ is not positive definite, then $A$ is not invertible, and so $Ax = b$ may not have a solution.  Matlab has a function called pcg that you could try using that solves $Ax = b$ with the conjugate gradient method.

Comment: @littleO Hi, thanks very much for your comments! If convenient, please refer https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.3933. In this paper, it seems the CG method is still slow.

Comment: That link doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @littleO, sorry, please check it again. It should be fine now. Thanks.

Comment: That's an interesting paper, I'm glad I saw it. A good preconditioner can improve the performance of the conjugate gradient method a lot, but choosing a preconditioner can be an art. At a glance I didn't see this paper discussing preconditioned CG for this problem, though maybe I missed it. Multigrid methods are very popular and sometimes extremely fast. I would guess the multigrid method in this paper is very good. I guess it will be hard to find a better method, although someone who is really an expert in numerical linear algebra might be able to do it.

Comment: On the other hand, it might be the kind of thing where if your research specialty is multigrid methods then you could easily play around with this problem and come up with something better than what's in the paper. I don't know this area well enough to judge.

Comment: @littleO, I'm greatly appreciated for your kind comments and suggestions! It seems the Multigrid methods in the paper is considering different levels of the 2D images, so I'm not sure if the methods can be generalized into 3D cases that I'm currently working on. My knowledge on PDE-based optimization is very limited. So I'm just looking for some libraries to solve the problem `Ax = b`. Thank you all the same. Your comments are very helpful!

Comment: What's the sizeof your matrix? From my experience, MATLAB does it somewhat fast if you declare it as `A=sparse(A)`

Comment: @GuilhermeK.Nakassima thanks for your comments! The size of matrix `A` might be 500000x500000.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer depends on properties of the matrix $ A $.

For large matrices sometimes iterative methods are faster than direct methods (Which is what behind `\`).
Try MATLAB [`pcg()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcg.html) (Preconditioned Conjugate Gradients Iterative Method) for instance.

Moreover, other properties also count.
For example, if the Matrix is Circulant Matrix, you better solve the system in the Fourier Domain.

If the matrix is Toeplitz, you better use [Levinson Recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levinson_recursion) (See my [Levinson Recursion Implementation)](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/Projects/tree/master/LevinsonRecursion).

So the best solver is the one which matches your matrix properties.

If the matrix is arbitrary and small to medium in its size, this operator is probably the fastest out there.
MATLAB uses Intel MKL behind the scene for solving those system.
Intel MKL is the fastest BLAS / LAPACK library out there.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer and kind suggestions! Currently the `pcg` function in MATLAB is working well in my project.